# Seg faults in Percona Server 5.6.19

Tags: mysql-5.6, percona-server, crash, archive

Trying to figure out what went wrong here. Any advice would be appreciated. This server is running a new installation of Percona Server 5.6.19 on CentOS 6.5

```
16:05:46 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.
Please help us make Percona Server better by reporting any
bugs at http://bugs.percona.com/

key_buffer_size=1073741824
read_buffer_size=1048576
max_used_connections=188
max_threads=2002
thread_count=177
connection_count=176
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 7228203 K  bytes  of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x17e85e60
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7f7c813f8d40 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2c)[0x8bb80c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x479)[0x6504b9]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x3af3a0f710]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN10ha_archive10unpack_rowEP11azio_streamPh+0xf5)[0xadb385]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN10ha_archive8rnd_nextEPh+0x7a)[0xadb8ba]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7handler11ha_rnd_nextEPh+0x5d)[0x597c5d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z13rr_sequentialP11READ_RECORD+0x20)[0x7f5780]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10sub_selectP4JOINP13st_join_tableb+0x101)[0x6adbf1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN4JOIN4execEv+0x2b8)[0x6ace68]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12mysql_selectP3THDP10TABLE_LISTjR4ListI4ItemEPS4_P10SQL_I_ListI8st_orderESB_S7_yP13select_resultP18st_select_lex_unitP13st_select_lex+0x275)[0x6f56b5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z13handle_selectP3THDP13select_resultm+0x165)[0x6f5f15]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x559ee0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THD+0x1cec)[0x6cfe3c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDPcjP12Parser_state+0x5c8)[0x6d5078]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_command19enum_server_commandP3THDPcj+0xfa7)[0x6d6807]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP3THD+0x162)[0x6a4882]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x40)[0x6a4970]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(pfs_spawn_thread+0x143)[0xb0dc13]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x3af3a079d1]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x3af36e8b5d]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7f7c380009a0): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 71
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems an invalid pointer was caught when doing a full table scan on the **Archive engine**. I recommend you to post the trace on [Percona Server bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-server/). Developers are very friendly even if you are not a client. They will be able to tell you **if it is a Percona specific problem or an upstream problem** (if they have changed anything on the Archive stored engine).

My own experience with the Archive engine is that, while it is a nice theoretical engine for some workloads, it is currently [mostly unmaintained and not ready for production](http://bugs.mysql.com/search.php?search_for=&bug_type[]=Server%3A%20Archive&status[]=Active&severity=&limit=30&order_by=&cmd=display&phpver=&os=0&os_details=&bug_age=0&tags=&similar=&target=&last_updated=0&defect_class=all&workaround_viability=all&impact=all&fix_risk=all&fix_effort=all&triageneeded=), having astounding bugs. [Percona does not recommend it](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2014/01/06/archive-storage-engine-expect/), and if you are concerned about stability, you are probably better served by InnoDB compressed or TokuDB (no matter if you are running PS or stock MySQL).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I filed a bug report with Percona and they say it's not a bug in their software. They did point me to an old upstream bug, but I don't think it applies in this case as archive tables in the 20G range are the norm with this application. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15787